# Show that if $A\subseteq B$, then inf $B\leq$ inf $A\leq$ sup $A \leq$ sup $B$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Is my logic correct or am I missing something?

Show that if $A\subseteq B$, then inf $B\leq$ inf $A\leq$ sup $A \leq$ sup $B$

Case 1. If $A \subset B$ then there exists $b_1,b_2\in B$ such that $b_1,b_2 \notin  A$. Let $a_1,a_2 \in A$ such that $a_1=$ inf A and $a_2$ = sup A. Suppose $b_1$=inf B and $b_2$=sup B than $b_1<a_1<a_2<b_2$ which implies inf $B<$ inf $A < $ sup $A<$ sup $B$

Case 2. If $A = B$ than every element in $A$ is in $B$. This implies that if $A$ is bounded above or below so is $B$ and vice versa. If the sup $B$ is defined to be the least upper bound and the inf $B$ is defined to be the greatest lowest bound. Than sup $B$ = sup $A$ and inf $B$ = inf $A$.

Since $A \subseteq B$ the following equality can be written as inf $B\leq$ inf $A\leq$ sup $A \leq$ sup $B$

Comment: You answered [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/476565) which asks the same question.

Comment: On a purely pedantic note, you almost assume that $A$ is nonempty. Otherwise the statement doesn't hold. :)

Answer (score 7):

Let's proceed by contradiction.

1)  inf B $\le$ inf A

Assume, to the contrary, that inf B > inf A.  Then there is some $x$ such that inf A < $x$ < inf B, but then $x \in A $ and $x \notin B$, a contradiction since $A \subseteq B$.  (Also note here: If I were being super rigorous I would need to appeal to the definition of infimum to make sure that $x$ is indeed in $A$.  Notice the strict inequality.)
Thus,  inf B $\le$ inf A

2)  sup A $\le$ sup B
Assume, to the contrary that sup A > sup B, then there exists some $x$ such that sup B < $x$ < sup A.  However, then $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$.  Again, a contradiction for the same reason as before.

3)  inf A $\le$ sup A.  By definition of sup and inf.

All together inf B $\le$ inf A $\le$ sup A $\le$ sup B.

Maybe someone can post a comment to help a little bit, what property of the real numbers am I using when I assume existence of $x$ like I do above?  Certainly it must exist since there are no gaps in the real numbers.  That way I can say that given two real numbers $a,b$ with $a <b$ then there exists $x$ such that $a <x <b$.  Is this the Archimedian property?  something topological?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is incorrect in Case 1: You've assumed that $b_1 = \inf{B} \in B \setminus A$. Take $A = (0, 1)$ and $B = (0, 2)$ to see why this is quite problematic.

---

For a hint towards the correct direction, can you show that any lower bound of $B$ is a lower bound of $A$ as well? So the greatest lower bound of $B$ is still a lower bound for $A$?

Comment: The sup and inf do not necessarily have to be in the set for example the sup $2-\dfrac{1}{n}$ is 2 since the limit of the sequence is 2. Is this correct?

Comment: @adam Yes, a set does not have to contain its sup or inf. That is a counterexample, as are my $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I rewrote case 1 to be this

Comment: Case 1. If $A \subset B$ then there exists $b_1,b_2\in B$ such that $b_1,b_2 \notin  A$. Let $a_1,a_2 \in A$ such that $a_1=$ inf A and $a_2$ = sup A. Let $b_1$ be a lower bound of $A$ and $b_2$ be a upper bound of $A$ Than there exist $b_3,b4$ such that for all $b \in B b_3<b$ and $b_4>b$. This implies that $b_3<b_1<a_1<a_2<b_2<b_4$ which implies inf $B<$ inf $A < $ sup $A<$ sup $B$

Comment: @adam $a_1$ and $a_2$ need not exist, as my example shows. There need not be *any* elements of $B$ which are lower bounds for $A$, so $b_1$ and $b_2$ might not exist either.

Comment: I think understand where you are coming from with the hint. If $A \subseteq B$ and $B$ is bounded above and below this implies that there exists $x$ and $y$ such that $x \leq b$ for all $b \in B$ and $y \geq b$ . Since $A \subseteq B$ this implies that $x$ and $y$ are lower and upper bounds of $A$ as well. This implies that the inf $B\leq$ inf $A\leq$ sup $A \leq$ sup $B$

Comment: @adam Yes. Every upper bound for $B$ is an upper bound for $A$, so the least upper bound for $B$ is still an upper bound for $A$.

Comment: So than this completes the proof of what we intended to show? But what if I had wanted to go about showing that if $A \subset B$ than inf $B<$ inf $A <$ sup$ A < $sup $B$? I do not think it would be the same thing because you would have to show the case where B is a open interval containing the set A. Thus you would have points that are in B that are lower and upper bounds of A. So would I just simply show that $x<b_1<b_2<y$ if $b_1$ and $b_2$ are lower and upper bounds of A respectively?

Comment: @adam You don't really need to break up into two cases with $A \subset B$ and not. Whether there is a point in $B$ which is an upper bound of $A$ doesn't really have an affect here.

Comment: So it is easier to work with points that are not in neither of the sets and show that they are upper and lower bounds of both sets since a upper bound is greater than the supremum and a lower bound is less than the greatest lower bound. So since we are able to make that statement. We are able to deduce that the inequality holds.

Answer (score 0):

let's suppose A ⊆ B⊆R  bounded  then we can say that through the known theorem for real numbers Completeness Property of R:
for every a ∈ A : infA ≤ a ≤ supA(1)
likewise for every b ∈ B : infB ≤ b ≤ supB

but at the same time A is the subset of B so we can say that every element of A is also bounded by the least upper bound  and the greatest lower bound of B
for every a ∈ A : infB ≤ a ≤ supB

but from the definition of the supremum and infimum we know that for random upper bound x and lower bound  y the supremum and infimum will always be smaller and greater likewise
for every a ∈ A : supA ≤x      and    y≤ infA (2)
in our problem we can assume the random bounds of x an y as x=supB   , y=infB

Through (1) and (2) we have our solution
inf B ≤ inf A ≤ sup A ≤ sup B

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).